# how to fix Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:28.0.3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-design-library

Below is my build.gradle and it's having the mentioned issue. please help me out

```
//noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.duosoft.duosoftticketingsystem"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0' // the lib is old dependencies version;
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v7:28.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    implementation 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.3'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    //    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

}
```

Comment: Where is your error?

Comment: use `appcompat-v7: 28.0.0`

Comment: try design:28.0.0

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i did that but again it said that that is less than minimum

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the `28.0.3` version of support libraries **don't exist**.

Try using:

```
  implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

**Note** : `28.0.0` is the last update in support libraries. All the future updates will be in `androidx` libraries.

You can check the [revision history](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions) and the [google maven repo](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) for the full release list.

```
27.0.2
27.1.0
27.1.1
28.0.0-alpha1
28.0.0-alpha3
28.0.0-beta01
28.0.0-rc01
28.0.0-rc02
28.0.0
```